# -Dojo- Getting the name of the file, that I want to upload

Tags: file, file-upload, upload, dojo, filenames

So I upload a file. After uploading the file i want to get the name of it like "picture.jpg" or "test.jar". I want the name because i want to put it in a textbox.

**Here is my code:**

```
var up = new dojox.form.Uploader({
    id:"up",
    label: 'Select jar File',
    multiple: false,
    url: '/echo/json/'
}).placeAt(uploadDialog);

var list = new dojox.form.uploader.FileList({
    id:"fileList",
    uploader: up
}).placeAt(uploadDialog);

var btn = new button({
    type: 'submit',
    label: 'upload',
    onClick: function() {
        up.upload();
    }
}).placeAt(uploadDialog);

//Close button
    closeButton3 =new button({label:"close",placement:"special",id:"closebtn3",class:"buttons"});

    daspect.after(closeButton3,"onClick",function(){ //Event closeButton
    uploadDialog.hide();
    var filename = document.getElementById("fileList").value;
    console.log(filename);
    });
    closeButton3.placeAt(uploadDialog,"last");


btn.startup();
up.startup();
list.startup();     
closeButton3.startup();
```

The URL doesn't work but this should not be a problem at the moment (i hope so).

Thank you very very much!

Comment: have you tried inspecting the 'list' object in a debugger? from memory (3 years since using it) it holds the native `File` objects, which contains the value of filename

Comment: Thank you! Now I i have the object. So i create a new variable with:
var filename =  up2.getFileList();!

Comment: no problem :) make an answer to your own question with how you figured it out, it might help someone else down the line

Answer (score 0):

**Problem solved!**

To get the name (an object with the propertie "name"), you can easily use a function.

my uploader is called "up", so i will get the object (that i want to upload) with the following code:

```
var filename = up2.getFileList();//Creates an object
```